How do you pass a bound method as a parameter in javascript?
I'm trying to pass a bound method to a function, but I can't quite figure out the syntax. It seems like javascript wants to somehow differentiate between an unbound method and a bound method, but where the calling context changes that. (Most programming languages simply define a method as a bound class function).
What's the syntax for passing a bound method to a function, and then calling that bound method in the new scope?
Here's the relevant snippets
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const caching = require('../lib/caching')

const Blog = mongoose.model('Blog');

// This is where I'm trying to pass a method to another function. I'm unclear of the syntax here
Blog.find = caching.makeCachable(Blog.find.bind(Blog), Blog)

module.exports = app => {
  app.get('/api/blogs', requireLogin, async (req, res) => {
    let blogs = await Blog.find({_user: req.user.id});
    return res.send(blogs);
  });

  // ... other routes
}

caching.js
const util = require('util');
const redis = require('redis');

const client = redis.createClient('redis://localhost:6379');
const asyncGet = util.promisify(client.get).bind(client);

const DEFAULT_CACHING = [
    'EX', 60 * 60 * 1,//caching expires after 4 hours
]

// This is where I take the method and pass it on to another function. I hope this just passes through
function makeCachable(method, thisObject) {
    console.log(method, thisObject, `${method.className}.${method.name}`);
    return cachedQuery.bind(method, `${thisObject.className}.${method.name}`);
}

async function cachedQuery(queryFunction, queryKey, queryParams=null, cacheConfig=DEFAULT_CACHING) {
    //check redis before executing queryFunction
    const redisKey = JSON.stringify([queryKey, queryParams]);
    const cacheValue = await asyncGet(redisKey);

    if(cacheValue) {
        return JSON.parse(cacheValue);
    }
    
    // This is where I try to call the bound method
    const blogs = await queryFunction.call(queryParams);
    
    if(blogs) {
        client.set(redisKey, JSON.stringify(blogs), ...cacheConfig);
    }

    return blogs;
}

exports.makeCachable = makeCachable;

EDIT
Apparently I wasn't clear enough about what doesn't work. This version of my code is after trying several combinations that don't work, but the error is always similar. For example, if I try to invoke const blogs = await queryFunction(queryParams); I get the following error
[0] E:\Documents\Code\nodejs_class\AdvancedNodeStarter\lib\caching.js:23
[0]     const blogs = await queryFunction(queryParams);
[0]                         ^
[0]
[0] TypeError: queryFunction is not a function
[0]     at Function.cachedQuery (E:\Documents\Code\nodejs_class\AdvancedNodeStarter\lib\caching.js:23:25)
[0]     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
[0]     at async E:\Documents\Code\nodejs_class\AdvancedNodeStarter\routes\blogRoutes.js:22:17
[0]

Similarly, I've tried, Blog.find = caching.makeCachable(Blog.find);, Blog.find = caching.makeCachable(Blog.find.bind(Blog));, I've tried invoking with .call() and without .call(). In all cases, I get some kind of error like the one above.
What I would expect from all other programming languages, with some slight syntactic differences is that Blog.find is a bound method. For example, C++ would let you reference &Blog.find or &Model::find for bound/unbound methods, respectively. Python lets you simply refer to Blog.find or Model.find for bound/unbound methods, respectively.
It seems in some situations javascript expects you to explicitly bind it. But for whatever reason, when I pass the function, bound or not, to makeCachable it seems to stop being a function. What is the actual syntax for passing a bound method to another function? Is there something extra that needs to be done to bind a method to another function parameter?

What is that .className property you are using (once with method and once with thisObject)? What is the purpose of the thisObject parameter you define for makeCacheable but do not really use in there? Why are you using cachedQuery.bind instead of creating a closure as would be the standard approach?

Why are you using queryFunction.call(queryParams) - did you mean to just call queryFunction(queryParams)?

For clarity, there is no essential difference between a reference to a function that is bound, and one that is not. The bound function is just a function, and the calling environment does not know or care about the binding.

Also, you cannot re-bind a bound method. Well, you can, but it doesn't work. The "deepest" bound method remains bound to the object it was originally bound to, and that is immutable.

"Why are you using cachedQuery.bind instead of creating a closure...?". I'm trying to assign a callable to Bind Blog.find = caching.makeCachable(Blog.find.bind(Blog), Blog). Anyways, closures are just functions without names. So why am I giving a name to the function instead of making it anonymous? shrug readability.

"Why are you using queryFunction.call(queryParams) - did you mean to just call queryFunction(queryParams)?" Because queryFunction(queryParams) didn't work. I tried that, and calling it with .call(). And calling it with .bind(). I can't figure out the combination that seems to work. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call. Do you know how to pass a bound method to another function? Why don't you just suggest a syntax that works?

"closures are just functions without names" - no, I was not talking about anonymous functions. Closures are functions with a scope. Just define cachedQuery inside makeCachable and get rid of one unnecessary (and apparently badly understood) level of indirection.

"I can't figure out the combination that seems to work" - you haven't really told us what doesn't work. How are you calling Blog.find? What did you expect to happen? What happened instead?

.bind accepts one or more arguments:

The first will be used as the this value within the function
The remaining arguments are curried, being used in order as the parameters of the function

Where you are doing:
cachedQuery.bind(method, `${thisObject.className}.${method.name}`)

What that actually means is that, within cachedQuery, the this value (that you're not using and don't need) is bound to method, and the queryFunction parameter is set to ${thisObject.className}.${method.name}.
If you're trying to just curry without binding anything, you could do:
cachedQuery.bind(null, method, `${thisObject.className}.${method.name}`)

However, note that there is no .className property on functions or objects, so this would always be undefined and your queryKey would look like 'undefined.find'. I assume you're looking for 'Blog'. The closest equivalent would be thisObject.constructor.name, but I would strongly recommend against using that as a pattern. Unlike class-based languages, the value doesn't have to be an instance of a class at all, e.g. const Blog = { find: () => null }, so it would just be 'Object'.
Thus, I think it would be clearer to supply the query key and do the currying explicitly:
Blog.find = caching.makeCacheable('Blog.find', Blog.find.bind(Blog))

// small nitpick, the word is cacheable, not cachable
function makeCacheable(queryKey, queryFunction) {
    return (queryParams = null, cacheConfig = DEFAULT_CACHING) => {
        return cachedQuery(queryFunction, queryKey, queryParams, cacheConfig)
    }
}

// no longer needs the default values as they're done in the curried function
// otherwise the same
async function cachedQuery(queryFunction, queryKey, queryParams, cacheConfig) {
    // ...
}



Thank you. That's both a correct answer, and good recommendations for style. I'll take your suggestion for explicitly passing the caching key.

Ok, I still don't know why, but here's a workaround. If I just change the makeCacheable function to use a closure instead of invoking bind explicitly, it works
function makeCachable(method, thisObject) {
    queryKey = `${thisObject.className}.${method.name}`;
    return function(queryParams=null, cacheConfig=DEFAULT_CACHING) {
        return cachedQuery(method, queryKey, queryParams, cacheConfig);
    }
}

I don't have an explanation for why return cachedQuery.bind(method, queryKey); doesn't work, but the closure does work.
